# Can I deploy a rest api to Hyperledger Fabric without ca-server?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, convector

I have successfully follow the instructions of this repository [fabric-network-on-swarm](https://github.com/dineshrivankar/fabric-network-on-swarm) and created a swarm network and successfully install and instantiate my own chaincode that I had already created with [convector](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/convector).

I have also created a [convector-rest-api](https://github.com/worldsibu/convector-rest-api) based on this repository.

In my setup I have created the certs with `cryptogen` and I can't find the way to inject the rest api to my containers without using a `fabric-ca-server` & `fabric-ca-client`

*-- Edited --*

(1) Can I create my own `network-profile.yaml` like this?:

```
name: "Network"
version: "1.0"

channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/keystore/9022d671ceedbb24af3ea69b5a8136cc64203df6b9920e26f48123fcfcb1d2e9_sk
    signedCert:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem


orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      grpc-max-send-message-length: 4194304
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tlscacerts/example.com-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tlscacerts/org1.example.com-cert.pem
```

Without adding information about my `certificateAuthorities`?

(2) With `crytogen` I generate crypto materials for `orderer` and my `peer`.
Which certificate should I use as my `keyStore` to connect my api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fabric-ca` is required when you want also to registry identities and issue certificates. However, if you use your own CA as `cryptogen`, it is not required the use of `fabric-ca` at the API. Instead of it, you should define the certificates that you will use for the connection, as well as the url of the Blockchain network. You have an example at the following [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html).

*--- Edited ---*

The following answers have been added to response to the two new questions asked by @StPaulis.

1. Yes, you can create your own `network-profile.yaml`. It's more, you must do it.
2. The credentials that you should use are those related to one of the users that you generate for the organization that own peers, for example, the admin keystore and signcert.